# What is an easy to use control flow library or module to use with mongoose and node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, control-flow

I was looking at async and step and I've been getting a lot of errors when making the database calls.

They both seem to work fine with the standard demo examples but as soon as I put in a mongoose db request it errors out, variables not defined, etc..

Does anyone have a working example I can look at?  Also, I noticed that there is a promise.js in mongoose and mongodb has a dependency on step.  Is that a clue to what I should use?

Comment: Async is the one I always use. If it's not working, then you're probably misunderstanding something. Could you post it bit of the code that was giving your errors?

Comment: +1 for async, there are methods to help almost any control flow situation

Comment: @LoganF.Smyth, indeed async.js works like a charm. It would be more appropriate to post the code and find out the solution to error rather then venturing out for another asynchronous library.

Comment: Got async working, thanks for the suggestions, it looks like that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like async works like a charm.  It was a simple syntax error on my part, extra spaces in my coffee script that was causing the problems.